# Inconsistent brightness values for AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, camera, avcapturesession, brightness

I'm trying to obtain the brightness of frames passed to an AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate from a AVCaptureVideoDataOutput object during an AVCapture session that uses the front camera of my iPhone using the didOutputSampleBuffer delegate:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        let dict = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, nil)
        if let brightness = dict!["BrightnessValue"] as? Double {
            print(brightness)    
        }
    }
```

It's important that this brightness be consistent. Within one session the brightness is consistent, but if I stop and restart the session programatically or by locking the device/exiting the application then the brightness values seem to shift. What I mean is, the brightness value that I receive when I block the camera changes between sessions.

I've tried fixing all the camera settings that I thought could possibly affect the apparent brightness in place:

```
try videoCaptureDevice.lockForConfiguration()

        videoCaptureDevice.autoFocusRangeRestriction = AVCaptureAutoFocusRangeRestriction.None
        videoCaptureDevice.smoothAutoFocusEnabled = false
        videoCaptureDevice.setExposureTargetBias(0.5) { (CMTime) -> Void in

        }

        if videoCaptureDevice.lowLightBoostEnabled {
            videoCaptureDevice.automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable = false
        }

        videoCaptureDevice.videoZoomFactor = 1.0
        videoCaptureDevice.automaticallyAdjustsVideoHDREnabled = false

        videoCaptureDevice.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.Locked

        videoCaptureDevice.setWhiteBalanceModeLockedWithDeviceWhiteBalanceGains(AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGains.init(redGain: 1.0, greenGain: 1.0, blueGain: 1.0), completionHandler: { (CMTime) -> Void in

        })

        videoCaptureDevice.setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition(0.5) { (CMTime) -> Void in

        }

        videoCaptureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
```

But this doesn't seem to have worked. I really can't figure out what's causing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

My answer may be almost a year late, but it still might be helpful to someone nonetheless. It looks like you didn't try setting the ISO. If you use:

```
device.setExposureModeCustomWithDuration(AVCaptureExposureDurationCurrent, iso: iso, completionHandler: nil)
```

Then you can set the ISO, which should stop the brightness values from changing too much.

A few additional tips, make sure you only do this once otherwise your values will once again be inconsistent after a second call. You must also first lock the device for configuration before calling the method mentioned above.